# Is there an algebraic condition on a map of rings which classifies whether the induced map on spectrum is closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism and let $\varphi \colon \text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ be the induced map on their spectrum. My question is: Is there any algebraic condition on $f$ which classifies when $\varphi$ is closed (sends closed sets to closed sets)? when $\varphi$ is a proper map (that is, the inverse image of a quasi-compact set is quasi-compact)?

I am looking for something in the vain of "$\varphi$ is dominant (has a dense image) if and only if every element of $\ker(f)$ is nilpotent".

(Note that there is no condition on neither $A$ nor $B$.)

Comment: Is [this kind of thing](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HZ) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Daniel Exactly, thanks! But what about properness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this stacks project lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HZ) proves that the closedness of the map $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is equivalent to the ring map $R \to S$ satisfying the 'going-up' property.

Any morphism between affine schemes is *quasi-compact*; meaning that the inverse image of a quasi-compact open set is quasi-compact. This is also proved in the stacks project [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01K4).

Note that I am not calling these kinds of maps *proper*, since properness has a distinct meaning in algebraic geometry: finite type, universally closed, and separated.